# PHP/MYSQL concurrency

Tags: php, mysql, concurrency, real-time

i am coding something like omegle random chat i have a table called chat_users in which
 i am storing ppl who are not chating with anyone they just come then i wil delete them when they start chating with other ppl

lets say 
we have users named uid1,uid2,uid3

at a 1:05 and 5 sec(one any perticular time) uid1 request to chat with uid2 and get removed from table
but at that same time uid3 also got uid2 as random result then it wil be problem 
cause uid2 doesnt exist its chating with uid1

how can i solve this issue??

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [transactions](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/ansi-diff-transactions.html).

Clarification: Wrap the selection of the random result and the following deletion in a transaction and the problem will go away because mySQL then should take care of colliding transactions.

Comment: @Smit: Well, it actually will. Why don't you give it a try?

Comment: what transaction concurrency do is maintain same state of database among all the users
but arrray is already loaded on one side and on otherside it gets removed from
database, transactions cant update in realtime so it wont solve it

Comment: i didnt start coding it
i am just figuring out what problems i will have to face in coding 
so i asked this one

Comment: I updated my answer. If you haven't tried it, how can you know it won't solve it? Come back if you tried it and it failed.

Comment: @minitech @tholu: I think there should be a `for update` at the end of each uid selection. if not here's my scenario: connection1 selects uid2 and at the same time connection2 also selects uid2; connection1 deletes uid2, commits transaction and returns uid2 to uid1; connection2 does the same thing, deletes uid2, commits transaction and returns uid2 to uid3. so am I wrong?